# Compare line by line within a linux file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file (test1.txt) like this:

```
100 100
200 200
300 HR
400 IT
500 500
600 600
```

And I want to desired output like this:

```
100 100 0
200 200 0
300 HR  1
400 IT  1
500 500 0
600 600 0
```

I already try to run this command:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk1=`awk '{print $1}' test1.txt`
awk2=`awk '{print $2}' test1.txt`

if [ "$awk1" = "$awk2" ]; then
        echo "0"
else
        echo "1"
fi
```

but the result is not as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$(NF+1)=$1==$2?0:1} 1' Input_file
```

OR to have output TAB delimited try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {$(NF+1)=$1==$2?0:1} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  $(NF+1)=$1==$2?0:1    ##Creating a new NF+1 field which will be newer last field and its value will be decided as per condition:
}                       ##If $1 and $2 are equal then set 0 or set 1 its value.
1                       ##1 will print the complete line value here(including new last field value).
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation is just to check field equality between `$1==$2`, and if they are equal, append `" 0"`, otherwise append `" 1"`, e.g.

```
$ awk '$1==$2{print $0" 0"; next } {print $0" 1"}' file
100 100 0
200 200 0
300 HR 1
400 IT 1
500 500 0
600 600 0
```

Which can be shortened to `awk '{print  $0, $1!=$2}' file` with a slight loss in readability.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
awk '{ printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n", $1, $2, $1 != $2 }' test1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is quite good but i wonder if sed can do it? So here it is a variant with sed.

```
sed 's/\(^.*\) \1/& 0/;t;s/$/ 1/' file
```

Explanation, first command `s/\(^.*\) \1/& 0/`

- \(^.*\) - define 1st column
- \1 - add copy of the 1st column

So we've got a 1st column and a copy of it in a pattern and if patern matched we change it to itself(`&`) + ' 0' then `t` will run next `s` command if firs didn't match. Second command `s/$/ 1/` simple add ' 1' to the end of the line.